# Django (urls.pu) экранирует символ #

Tags: python, django

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Допустим, нужно, чтобы url вида /tag/c# вел на соответствующую вьюху, но после перехода по ссылочке в адресной строке остается только /tag/c. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, дело было в том, что в темплейте я url задавал явно, при использовании `{% url 'viewname' %}` все заработало.

Comment: решетка не передается по хттп

Comment: решетка как ascii символ url стала %23, поэтому заработало. Сам же знак # используется как якорь, поэтому не может работать в url. Для наглядности решетка%23  и решетка# Первое можно использовать как часть пути в джанго, второе нет.